# Not displaying the search result

Tags: php, mysql, search-engine

```
<?php    $query = $_GET['search-text'];          
$min_length = 3;         
if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ 

    $query = htmlspecialchars($query);             
    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);

    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE (`title` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());               

    if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ 

        while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){                 

        }

    }
    else{
        echo "No results";
    }

}
else{ 
    echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
}    ?>
```

well i have not specified the database connection here.

my html code

```
<form id="frm-search" action="search.php" method="GET">
<div class="m-search">
<input type="hidden" id="search-text-value" name="search-text-value">
<input type="text" id="search-text" maxlength="150" class="search-text" name="search-text" placeholder="search" value="" autocomplete="off" onblur="" style="color: rgb(140, 140, 140);">
<input type="image" src="spray/search.png" value="" class="search-btn">
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</form>
```

it's showing undefined index search-text and results.and when i try to search it does not display anything.

i have echo it after the form tag.

Comment: You are doing nothing inside your `while` loop.

Comment: you have to have url like webpage.com/index.html?search-text=$query on your url bar if you use GET method. I think the problem is with getting value from the form.

Comment: Your sample doesn't do anything, empty loop, fix question

Comment: http://test.loke/website3/search.php?search-text-value=&search-text=kriss&x=86&y=9 this what i get after i submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like echo $results[index]; inside while loop !
and 
change SQL to :

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE '$query%'");
```

Comment: well what if i want the result to be displayed on somewhere else .and if i do echo$results['title']; inside while loop the result is displaying on top of the page but  its still showing undefined index "search-text" and "results".why ?

Comment: if you want to display somewhere , store in variable like $name = $results["name"];

Comment: replace mysql_fetch_array with mysql_fetch_assoc

Comment: SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE '$query%'

Comment: yes i have done it.the result displaying properly but when i open the page showing that undefined index error.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: search-text in C:\wamp\www\test\website3\search.php on line 13 and Notice: Undefined variable: title in C:\wamp\www\test\website3\search.php on line 104v

Comment: do you have url like 

webpage.com/index.html?search-text=$query on your url bar when you see this ?

Comment: its hard to say what going on but try changing search-text-value to search-text in html code.

Comment: no i dont have url when i see this http://test.loke/website3/search.php only this i see.and i have tried but still getting the errors.